# Swiftui enter value in TextField then button click need change Text - not working

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am enter value in TextField then i button click, after click i need change Text and put my result but my code not working, could you help me

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var numeral: Double = 0.00
    @State var result: Double = 0.00

    var body: some View {
        VStack{

            TextField("Enrer numeral", value: self.$numeral, formatter:  NumberFormatter())
                .padding(20)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                .font(.largeTitle)

            Text("\(result)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()

            Button(action: {
                self.result = self.numeral*1.2

                print(self.result)
                print("sfsdfd")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)

            }
        }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems while using `value:` as an input, SwiftUI does not reload the view.

SwiftUI reloads the view using `text:` as an input whenever a key is pressed.

do it using below approach.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var numeral : String = "0.00"
    @State var result: Double = 0.00

    var body: some View {

       VStack {

            TextField("Enrer numeral", text: $numeral)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad) 
                .padding(20)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                .font(.largeTitle)

            Text("\(result)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()

            Button(action: {

                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                if let val = Double(self.numeral) {
                    self.result = val * 1.2
                    print(self.numeral)
                    print(self.result)
                }
                else {
                    print("Entered value is invalid")
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
Button(action: {
    // force textfield to commit
    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), 
       to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)

    self.result = self.numeral*1.2

    print(self.result)
    print("sfsdfd")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, but this should work for you on ios devices and macos catalyst.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var numeral: Double = 0.00
@State var result: Double = 0.00

var body: some View {
    VStack{

        TextField("Enrer numeral", text: Binding<String>(
            get: { String(format: "%.02f", self.numeral) },
            set: {
                if let value = NumberFormatter().number(from: $0) {
                    self.numeral = value.doubleValue
                }}))
            .padding(20)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
            .font(.largeTitle)

        Text("result \(result)")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding()

        Button(action: {
            self.result = self.numeral * 1.2
            print("---> result: \(self.result)")
            // if you want to reset the TextField value
            self.numeral = 0.00
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}
}
```